# Create pdf file from ArrayList<String> using pdfbox in JAVA

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I need help to create a PDF file from a `ArrayList` of strings.
I have tried to fix this for so long but I have not succeeded, can someone please help me?

I don't know what else to write here I think the title says everything. So have someone out there had the same problem or knows how to create the PDF file?

The `parsedText` is the whole text I have extracted from another PDF file.

The code:

```
    String[] splitText = parsedText.split("\\."); 
    newList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(splitText));


    PDDocument doc = null;
    PDPage page = null;
    try{
        doc = new PDDocument();
        page = new PDPage();

        doc.addPage(page);
        PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
        PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(doc,page);

        content.beginText();
        content.setFont(font, 12);
        content.moveTextPositionByAmount(100, 700);
        String text = "";
        for(int i=0; i<newList.size();i++)
        {
            if(sentence.isEmpty()) continue;
            content.drawString(newList.get(i) + "\n");

        }

        content.endText();
        content.close();
        doc.save("nameoffile.pdf");
        doc.close();
        System.out.print("Pages" + pdDoc.getNumberOfPages());

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: http://pdfbox.apache.org/cookbook/documentcreation.html What exactly is not working and what have you tried?

Comment: _I have not succeeded_. How so? Care to show us your failed attempt?

Comment: Every index in the arraylist is a sentence and when i try to write the arraylist in the pdf file it writes a single line with the arraylist. It wont break and start with a new line like normal text is.

Comment: You have to position the text. Look at the link in my first comment. Note the line `contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount( 100, 700 );` in the second example.

Comment: I do have that line of code, i will try to edit the question and add the code. As you can see I'm new to SOF and sorry for my poor post.

Comment: I hope the edit i have done helps to understand the problem.

Comment: You have to call that method with the desired line height in every iteration of the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need:

```
for(int i=0; i<newList.size();i++)
{
    if(sentence.isEmpty()) continue;
    content.drawString(newList.get(i));
    content.moveTextPositionByAmount(0, LINE_HEIGHT);
}
```

to update the text position for each line. Think of it a little bit like drawing to a graphics context.

If you want empty lines for "" - entries then drop the first line in the loop.

Comment: Thank you this took me a step closer! I will try to improve the result i have now

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question and answer & I am putting a new answer by modifying your code  as multiple methods from Apache PdfBox API have got deprecated.

First you don't need the line , `newList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(splitText));` as you can directly work on `String[]`.

Second problem in your code is that you are using `\n` to create a new line & that wouldn't work in case of pdf creation. All your sentences will be printed in one line. You have to explicitly position your text pointer to next line.

I have put hard coded content into `String[] splitText` . I have line width as 20 points.

Attached is the image of generated pdf file as well.

```
public static void createPdf() {
    String[] splitText = new String[] { "Line 1", "Line 2", "", "Line 3 " };
    try (PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();) {
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        doc.addPage(page);
        PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
        PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
        content.setFont(font, 12);
        int lines = 1;
        for (String sentence : splitText) {
        if (sentence.isEmpty()) {
            continue;
        }
        content.beginText();
        content.newLineAtOffset(100, 700 - 20f * lines);
        content.showText(sentence);
        content.endText();
        ++lines;
        }
        content.close();
        doc.save("nameoffile.pdf");
        System.out.print("Pages" + doc.getNumberOfPages());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: While your code is probably correct, it has one (very small) weakness compared to the accepted answer: you are using `beginText` and `endText` for every line, instead of doing this relatively. So your PDF will be longer.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr: Thanks for pointing out. I am very new to this API and I struggled a little bit to write non - deprecated code as most of posts are using deprecated code so I thought to put this answer. I will try to revise code but you pls also feel free to do that.